# Can I create a form for a nested resource without the parent record until I save?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-resources, simple-form-for

I have two models `Player` and `MicroReport`.  `MicroReport` is a nested resource of `Player`.  I'm trying to create a separate form to allow users to create a `MicroReport` without having to first navigate to a Player's page and then create the report.  Is this possible?

I'm was going to try and use the form below, where they could select a player during the creation of the form - but to my knowledge I'd need to specify a player record here (which it currently doesn't exist).

```
<%= simple_form_for [@micro_report.player, @micro_report] do |form| %>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <%= form.input :author_id, as: :hidden, input_html: { value: current_user.id } %>
      <%= form.input :player, input_html: { class: "player-search-box-for-micro-report" }, 
           data: { autocomplete_source: auto_complete_searches_path } %>
      <%= form.input :grade, collection: Grade.joins(:scale)
           .where(scales: { name: "Skill Scale" } ) %>
      <%= form.input :summary, label: "Summary" %>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-actions">
    <%= form.button :submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>

class Player < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :micro_reports
end

class MicroReport < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :author
  belongs_to :player
  belongs_to :grade
end
```

**routes.rb**

```
resources :players do
 scope module: :players do
   resources :micro_reports  
 end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that case you need to add `optional: true` to the `belongs_to :player`.

```
belongs_to :player, optional: true
```

From the [Documentation](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-belongs_to-label-Options)

> `required` is set to true by default and is deprecated. If you don't
>   want to have association presence validated, use `optional: true`.

With this setup in place, you can create `MicroReport` records without adding `Player` records on creation.

Comment: So if I do it that way what would this line be changed to... `<%= simple_form_for [@micro_report.player, @micro_report] do |form| %>`

Comment: it will be `<%= simple_form_for @micro_report do |form| %>` As you are creating just  micro reports here.

Comment: I updated my post with the relevant routes.rb information.  When I use the recommened line you suggest I get the following error: `undefined method 'micro_reports_path' for #<#<Class:0x00007f219ea61528>:0x00007f21d5ac17e8>`.

Comment: You need to change route.. Right now you have nested routes as far as I can tell. So create new routes, controllers for this form.. This new routes, controller and form will be responsible to do CRUD for microposts.

Comment: Ahh duh, haha ok thanks for the help. Really appreciate it!

Comment: @daveomcd Yeah no problem. Sometimes it is hard to understand what is going on the other side. :)